# Excel file output in r with data validation

Tags: r, excel

I am getting an excel sheet created through r script from a data frame. In one of the columns need data validation. Is it possible to get the data validation in place while running the r script and output file in excel format?

Comment: It is possible, but would need some additional information on what kind of validation you're after. Can you expand your question to reflect this?

Comment: Yes , actually i want to insert a list containing some Words that should go as  validation